# Why does the horizontal scroll bar appear when

Tags: html, css

On [this site](http://fredfigglehorn.com), a horizontal scroll bar appears if the browser is resized to a certain size. Here's an attached image of what I mean. Notice the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom and the image cutting off even though the backgrounds are set to repeat-x.

[image]

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Some element has a widht that is larger than the current size of the window

Comment: Did you scroll down in the page?

Comment: @George Yeah, that's what I figured. I've been looking through the code and there is nothing that stands out. Thanks for helping me confirm the problem.

Comment: @David Yes, just did. Not sure what you're getting at though...

Comment: If you highlight the `<div id="grass-bg">` element (below the `<!-- #wrapper -->` comment), you'll find that its width is explicitly set to 1408px.

Comment: @David, I am not seeing that through Firebug. There is no width set for #grass-bg. I even searched through my style sheet for "1408" and nothing was found. Where do you see the width set to 1408px?

Comment: Highlight it with the inspector, and then look at 'metrics' on the right (I used Chromium's Web Inspector tools, but I recall that Firebug has something similar...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the `iframe` inside `#fb-root` element in facebook-like section, that has a width of 575px

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to identify without code.  Either post some code or install Chrome, right click and "inspect element" to find the offending element.

As above - there is clearly an element that has a width > than the body